# xap loading error on asp.net development server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express, cassini, windows-update, aspnet-development-server

Recently I started to get a strange error,
While loading xap file it stops! In %95 in %4 very random .

There is an error in browser's developer console

**Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight 
Application 
Code: 2104

Category: InitializeError

Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings**

When I opened all debugging options I see that

**System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred

**Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10054
  NativeErrorCode=10054
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
  InnerException:**

On fiddler I can clearly see that 4 of 7MB xap is downloadin and breaks!

Note: This error only occurs on iis-express and asp.net dev.server. On deployment platform everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Days later one of my friend also encountered this error in office,

So we realized our pc's updated recently by update server. But some windows updates doesn't exist on other PCs.

Firstly we removed VS2010 updates but it didn't solve.
Finally we uninstalled recent windows updates. (This cause windows reset,and takes time to remove this updates)

Which KB12XX?? we don't know(if someone inspect it please share), but after reboot it works like a charm.

Hope helps someone!